# jQuery Table Sorter not working with IE 9

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, visualforce

I am using jQuery Table Sorter with Apex (Salesforce). I am listing table with 6 columns and two of them are input field. The Table sorts perfectly with Fire Fox, Chrome, IE 8 but i have a strange behaviour with IE 9 alone.
Actually the sorting works in IE 9 too. But when ever I try to sort even one time, it erases all the input value to null.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this demo of a custom parser that allows you to sort a column using the input values:

[Dynamic input value sorting](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/vCTHw/71/)

Sadly, this parser will not work on the original tablesorter plugin, but it will on my github forked version of [tablesorter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter).

```
// add parser through the tablesorter addParser method
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: 'inputs',
  is: function(s) {
    return false;
  },
  format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
    var $c = $(cell);
     if (!$c.hasClass('updateInput')) {
      $c
      .addClass('updateInput')
      .bind('keyup', function() {
        $(table).trigger('updateCell', [cell, false]); // false to prevent resort
      });
    }
    return $c.find('input').val();
  },
  type: 'text'
});

$(function() {
  $('table').tablesorter({
     headers: {
      3: {
        sorter: 'inputs'
      }
    }
  });
});​
```